# prefer user thread rather than kernel thread

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, multicore

I have two question , that I don't know which one is better and when?

1.do we have any time that prefer single core rather than multi-core?when all of the cores are the same as each other?

2.when we prefer using the kernel thread and when we prefer using the user thread? do we have any time which we prefer to use only the user thread?I mean when we prefer implementing our program using kernel level and when user level thread?

an example : 
I want to read some files from disk and do some operation on each of these files, which one is better to choose?

- multi-core system using kernel level thread
- multi-core system using user level thread
- single-core system using user level thread
- single-core system using kernel level thread

Comment: Both of your questions are so vague that we can't tell what you're asking. Do you mean single core CPUs over multi-core CPUs where the two CPUs might be completely different otherwise? Or do you mean all else being equal, we'd prefer a single core CPU to a CPU that had more cores each identical to the single core? Or what? And in the second question, do you mean prefer to schedule them? Or do you mean prefer to implement something using a kernel thread?

Comment: sorry, I've corrected it.does it get better? @DavidSchwartz

Comment: Prefer on which grounds? We prefer single core over multiple cores, for instance, for the sake of cost efficiency....

Comment: I have completed my question, can u see it again ? @SergeyA

Comment: What do you mean by "some operations"? Do you mean computation-intensive operations?

Comment: Yes I mean that @DavidSchwartz

Comment: Is the data large enough to generate page-faults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As long as the other cores don't actively violate any invariant of the (on a single core running) program, then there's theoretically no reason to choose single core over multi core. In practice, though, there are quite a few things one should consider:

   - Cache misses, caused when the program is scheduled to different cores. Only if the cores have their own caches. Also, this can be prevented in modern operating systems.
   - Potentially more interrupts to handle: Other cores could be running code that causes them to emit [inter-processor interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-processor_interrupt)

   Moreover, there are obviously non technical issues like cost and availability to be considered.
2. In general, user level threads seem to be more efficient than kernel level threads. So for e.g. parallel computation I'd recommend user level threads.

   > I want to read some files from disk and do some operation on each of these files, which one is better to choose?

   The example you give could, on the other hand, require the use of
   kernel level threads: Reading files and other interactions with anything outside of the program usually involves issuing system calls. Many of them will be *blocking* system calls, blocking an entire kernel thread. This also means that all (if any) user level threads running on this kernel thread will be blocked.

   Whether you can take advantage of the additional processing power a multi core system provides depends highly on the specific task at hand and to what grade it is parallelizable.

Comment: thanks for your good answer :)

Comment: "Whether you can take advantage of the additional processing power a multi core system provides depends highly on the specific task at hand and to what grade it is parallelizable." So in my example you offer multi-core system ?@DanielJour

Comment: That depends on what you do with the data from the files. Opening files in parallel is nice, but not really a performance factor.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I can possibly imagine (and it takes a lot of imagination for this) where a user thread would be preferable to a kernel thread is when there is some unique type of locking issue where you needed to ensure only one thread was executing.

The only time for practicable purposes to use user threads is when kernel threads are not available.

Comment: How about green threads used by e.g. "newcomer" languages such as Go and established languages such as e.g. Erlang?